# Reading from configuration file within WCF web service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, web-config

I'm trying to read from `Constants.config` file within not ASP.NET enabled WCF web service.

```
Configuration rootWebConfig1 = Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("Constants.config");
```

This call threw an exception, and it's seems like that `OpenWebConfiguration` tries open the config file in some different location. How can I know where it looks for and how can I specify the target folder?

Thanks a lot.
Ilan.

Comment: **WHAT** exception did it throw?? Please provide all revelant details

Comment: Because I do it in static constructor, the message of the exception is something that it's something wrong with the type. Not something useful.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenWebConfiguration` is intended to open a **web configuration file** - e.g. a `web.config` only...

You can't use it to open your own config files, as far a I know.

You can however use the regular `Configuration` class from the .NET `System.Configuration` namespace. Check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject:

- Part 1: [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- Part 2: [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- Part 3: [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful!

In part 3, Jon shows how you can use your own custom config files and open them with the help of the `ExeConfigurationFileMap` class:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap exeMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
exeMap.ExeConfigFilename = "C:\Application\Constants.config";

Configuration exeConfig = 
  ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(exeMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: The [Configuration class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) is deprecated, [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) should be used. However, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do what [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) said and use the [Configuration (depreciated)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) or [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx), or if you want you WCF service to support ASP.NET features you can turn on [ASP.NET Compatability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx) by decorating your service implementation with an [AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute.aspx).

If the service will be tied to an ASP.NET site, always hosted in IIS, and would be making use of the ASP.NET session, this is probably the way to go. If not use the ConfigurationManager class.